# linux container on docker windows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: linux, windows, docker, browser

im new with docker i installed the latest docker for windows
but when run linux container on docker windows and i try to open http://localhost:5104/ in the browser i just get an empty response. Chrome: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

[image]

Comment: Need much more info, what application are you trying to run, what commands are you using, etc.

Comment: dot net core  web application :)

Comment: Can you update with your Docker command ```docker run ...``` and if possible your Dockerfile too.